# How to install rofi 1.6 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I want to install rofi 1.6 on ubuntu 18.04

But in the repositories only the version is available 1.5.0 and some extensions depend on newer versions

Is there a way to update the version?

Comment: You will likely need to compile yourself, unless a PPA would exist somewhere. It may be recommended to upgrade your operating system - latest LTS release is 20.04 - which will give you easy access to a more recent version of Rofi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a PPA by *Constantin Piber*](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecppiber/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) with newer 1.6.1 version of rofi. To use it open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cppiber/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rofi
```

Comment: thank you very much, how did you find the repository?

Comment: Two methods exist - [online](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) and local by using previously installed [Y PPA Manager application](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager).